# Convergence of gradient descent with ordinary least squares

Tags: regression, machine-learning, optimization, least-squares, gradient-descent

I am currently trying to understand the numerical optimisation of the Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) approach to linear regression using gradient descent. So let us define the associated optimisation problem as: [image]

By using batch gradient descent, one can update the weight parameter until the convergence of the objective function within some tolerance parameter, by following the rule, where X is a matrix of observations and y is the corresponding output for each observation.
[image]

I am trying to understand under what conditions on α_t will the batch gradient descent step converge for OLS in general.

Thank you for your time!